# How to make the second Function await until the first function gets done?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am a JavaScript beginner, and trying to figure out how to make appendElement wait until createForm done, without using setTomeout(). As createForm is, a div pop up with a button fires updateValues(). I want to appendElement to wait until updatesValues() sets localStorage values so that change on localStorage is going ot be reflected. AppendItem creates card based on values in localStorage. Currently, I  have to refresh the page to see the result on local storage. I tried to use async, but appendElement would never wait.
Let me know your insight. Thanks!

### Create form

[image: Pop up]

[image: Current outcome]

[image: Prefabl outcome]

### JS

```js
async function addPlace (){
    await createForm(idNum);
    appendElement("listParent", idNum)
    idNum += 1  
};

async function createForm(number){
        console.log(`locationName_${number}`)
        let items = `key, phone, book,...`
    
        let newForm = `
        <div id="container" class="d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="reveal-modal d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3" id="exampleModal">
            <div class="mb-3 d-flex flex-column ">
                <label for="locationName" class="form-label">Location</label>
                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="updateLocationName_${number}" placeholder="Location Name">
    
                <label for="Lost items" class="form-label">Lost items<br>Please separate items with comma (,)</label>
                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="updatedLocationItems_${number}" placeholder="${items}">
            </div
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deleteListCard('\container\')">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updateValues(${number})">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        `
        const parentDom = document.querySelector('body')
        parentDom.innerHTML += newForm
        await updateValues(number)

    }

async function updateValues(number){
    console.log(`${number} is updated!`)
    let updatedName = document.getElementById(`updateLocationName_${number}`).value
    let updatedItems = document.getElementById(`updatedLocationItems_${number}`).value
    console.log(updatedName)
    console.log(updatedItems)

    const itemArr = updatedItems.split(',')

    // set Array

    localStorage.setItem(`locationName_${number}`, updatedName)
    localStorage.setItem(`locationItems_${number}`, JSON.stringify(itemArr))
    deleteListCard('container') //exit popup
}

//Appned List
function appendElement(parentID, number){
    const parentDom = document.getElementById(parentID)

    if(document.getElementById("stevens_barbar")){
        deleteListCard("stevens_barbar")
    }

    let location = localStorage.getItem(`locationName_${number}`)
    let storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`locationItems_${number}`))
    
    parentDom.innerHTML += `
    <div id="location_${number}">
        <h1>${location}</h1>
        ${generateCheckbox(storedItems)}
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updateLocalstorage('${number}')">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning delete_button" onclick="deleteListCard('\location_${number}\')">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
}
```

Comment: there's nothing obviously asynchronous inside `updateValues`, since you never `await`, so why is it `async`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
await createForm(idNum);
```

The `await`ed function is supposed to return a Promise, but `createForm` doesn't.  There is nothing in your code that requires or manipulates promises and everything runs synchronously (except probably for `deleteListCard` which we don't see).  No need for `asyns`/`await`.